# iOS ZXing 2.2 crash on FinderPattern, throwing zxing::ReaderException("Could not find three finder patterns")

Tags: ios, zxing

I am using CocoaPods to install ZXing 2.2 on my app, and it works fine until iOS 7 comes out. ZXing will crash 
when I am scanning the qrcode, the crash info is here:

- Crash on the **FinderPatternFinder.cpp**, break at this point:

  ```
  if (startSize < 3) {
      // Couldn't find enough finder patterns
      throw zxing::ReaderException("Could not find three finder patterns");
    }
  ```
- The thread info is:
  [image: crash thread stack]

Can anyone to help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You might want to see the Objective-C port of ZXing at https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, I am checking ZXingObjC now.